# The trouble with $scope

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, angularjs

I have an input file element within an angular view/form. I'm using [ng-upload](https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload) like this:

```
<input id="img" type="file" name="image" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this)">
<input id="imgname" type="hidden" value=""></div>
```

Since I can't tell angular to listen for changes on `input[type="file"]` element, I've created the method that updates the hidden input that just holds the current filename. That way I can run my validator on the second field.

Another field I have has some sort of validator, like this:

```
<input ng-model="other" ng-change="chg()"/>
```

Now, the trouble is, if I trigger the validator, `$scope.chg()`, from `setFile()` method, I think I don't get the same scope - `chg()` runs, but it's as if the validator is in another scope and doesn't set my actual submit button to enabled. I tried logging from the chg() - it shows different scope then what I actually see on the view.

And if I later trigger the ng-change by changing the regular input field (**"other"**), it picks up the changes, or actually, it sets the submit button state correctly.

Now, I suspect this has to do with me calling the *angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this)* from my form instead of direct, $scope-bound method. But I cannot call $scope-bound method because it does not trigger - if I understood correctly, that's due to Angular not (yet) working with *input type=file* fields.

What can I do here?

I simply want to detect if there is a file or not so I can enable/disable the submit button appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used followed flow that works for me:

```
<input type="file"
       ng-model="upFile"  
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFileEventListener(this)"
 />
```

From controller:

```
$scope.setFileEventListener = function(element) {
        $scope.uploadedFile = element.files[0];

        if ($scope.uploadedFile) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.upload_button_state = true;
            });   
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help.